# findViewById for drawer_layout always returns null

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement navigation drawer but `findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)` always returns `null`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.customToolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Title");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        createDrawerNavigation();
}

private void createDrawerNavigation() {
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            Log.v("","DDDDDDDDDDDD");
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
```

app_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

when i click on menu button app crashes with this error-

````
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference```
````

Comment: You are using `R.layout.activity_main` for your `setContentView()` call, but you've titled your xml file posted here as `app_drawer.xml`. Unless this is `<include>`-ed in `activity_main.xml`, this is probably the reason why the drawer can't be found.

Comment: Are you sure the R.layout.activity_main has the View inside?

Answer (score 1):

You have named your layout file `app_drawer.xml`, but in your Activity you are invoking `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main).`

Either change your layout file name to `activity_main.xml`, or change the line in your java code to `setContentView(R.layout.app_drawer)`;